# Authenticate Azure Active Directory

Tags: excel, vba, azure, azure-active-directory

I have an excel file that has a macro on it.  I want only the users that are member of a certain Azure Active Directory user group, be able to run the macro.  How can I code the Azure authentication part in VBA?

Thanks so much!

Cheers,
Alan

Comment: I haven't tried the following - it seems to be a vbscript solution https://rdr-it.com/en/scripts/vbs-check-if-a-user-is-part-of-a-group/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for Azure AD the Client libraries/SDKs that are supported are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-v2-libraries) and you will note that VBA is not one of them.

VBA language wise is a pretty limiting factor here.  I might try to implement a web endpoint/website that you call from the VBA that is AAD integrated (App Services can help with that) and then in the response indicate your yes/no or groups for your VBA code to read.

So:  VBA Code makes HTTP call to Website with AAD integration, (user logs in if needed) Website then responds back to VBA with some JSON or other payload.  VBA reads payload and then acts accordingly.

That website can use the Microsoft Graph to pull all memberships they have in AAD.  Play with the Graph explorer here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer and try this endpoint: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http